# iOS AVPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:nil block UI Thread

Tags: ios, avplayer, ui-thread

It seems that the api replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem: will stuck the main thread for some seconds, I understand that replacing the item need the information of the new item which might take some time to preload. But questions come up that why replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem: with a **nil item object** would also stuck the main thread?? It happens to me that sometimes it take more than 5 seconds to replace a nil playerItem.
I wonder what can I do to avoid the issue. Thanks for any advices!

Answer (score 4):

I came across a similar blocking UI thread issue when I used `UICollectionView` to display and preview video in local photo library via `ALAssetLibrary`.

The scroll on switching videos is not smoothly,so I guess some method block UI thread.Then **I use `Core Animation` of `Instruments` to analyze what exactly occupy the UI thread**.In `Time Profiler` I found out that `replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem` need about 30ms to execute in main thread,which is more than 16ms (1000/60(fps)) result in choppy scrolling.

To solve the problem,first I tried that put `replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem` in to background thread using GCD,but It not work.I'm not sure if it is because the Cocoa itself need update UI when call `replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem`,which means the UI thread is still block.Finally I made it work by putting `replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem` at the scrolling end (the delegate `func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView)`).Now the scrolling is smoothly,yep!

Therefore,my advice is obvious : **Using Instruments to analyse what exactly occupy the UI thread**